# automatically execute system command when saving all files

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to figure out how to get VS Code to automatically execute system commands when I save all files. And, if possible, pass the path to the root/main folder to the command. For example, say I have `C:\users\nacho\path\to\some\folder` opened and it has numerous files and sub-folders with their own files.

No matter what file I'm currently/actively editing, when/if I save-all files I want to run the system command `someCommand "C:\users\nacho\path\to\some\folder"`.

Is this possible? I saw the build tasks but that requires me to run the build command. I want it to trigger automatically anytime I save all files.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Run on Save](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=emeraldwalk.RunOnSave)

> This extension allows configuring
>   commands that get run whenever a file is saved in vscode.
>
> NOTE: Commands only get run when saving an existing file. Creating new
>   files, and Save as... don't trigger the commands.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to trigger on save, not save-all. It doesn't look like VS Code has a trigger/event for save-all.